# Type 'number' is not an array type on react typescript reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting this error when finding an index, and trying to decrement a number value. I'm using typescript with react.

> Type 'number' is not an array type.  TS2461

here is the code

**reducer**

```
import produce from "immer";
import * as types from "../actionTypes/postActionTypes";

export interface postState {
  posts: Array<any>;
}

const initialState: postState = {
  posts: []
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action: any): postState =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
       .....
      case types.DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action);
        const newfindKey = state.posts.findIndex(
          x => x.id === action.payload.id
        );
        console.log(newfindKey);
        draft.posts[newfindKey] = [...(draft.posts[newfindKey].likeCounts - 1)];
        return;

  });

export default postReducer;
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau `draft.posts[newfindKey] = [...(draft.posts[newfindKey].likeCounts - 1)];`

Comment: Why are you using the spread operator on "likeCounts - 1" which is a number and not array.

Comment: i need to spread this out, or the like counts will not be returned, im following another example on a similar app using immer, and it works well, but this is using typescript.

Comment: Link to that example?

Comment: i found the solution by some trial and error, will post answer below

Answer (score 1):

instead of spreading the object, i just did this instead. It now decrements the likeCounts value.

```
case types.DISLIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
  console.log(action);
  const newfindKey = state.posts.findIndex(
    x => x.id === action.payload.id
  );
  draft.posts[newfindKey].likeCounts = draft.posts[newfindKey].likeCounts - 1;
```

Comment: Great. Can you share the example you were looking at. Curious to see how that was done.

Comment: Sure, it was a last side project of mine https://github.com/EliHood/ReactExpressPhotoShareApp/blob/master/client/src/reducers/imageReducer.js